# Avoid login auth in Docusign

Tags: python, docusignapi

For regular flow: a user has to login (in docusign view) to get a code to get token and upload his docummnet.
I want to user my personal account to get this token without login in docusign view. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JWT for this.

"In the JWT bearer authentication flow, your application posts a JWT to the DocuSign authentication service, asserting its credentials and providing the data of the user that it wishes to impersonate (act on behalf of). DocuSign validates that the assertion is signed and that your application has the permission to act on behalf of the user, then issues an access token that allows you to call DocuSign APIs."

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-jsonwebtoken