# DocuSign : login without user consent

Tags: java, docusignapi

I'm new to docusign.

**EDIT** : this part was not clear, so I edited it :

Here is my need : I'm developping a webapp. There will be only 1 user on the webapp, and this user won't need to sign any document (very important). His role with docusign is only to create an electronic signature between 2 or more people. The signers will sign the documents on the docusign platform.

It's like the user doesn't even need to know we use docusign (or any other provider) to emit electronic signature requests

**The reason why I do this** : the user pays for the whole webapp, not for the docusign account. So in fact we (the webapp developers) are the only people who possess the docusign account

The most usefull help I've found told me to use JWT flow [Avoid login auth in Docusign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59360052/avoid-login-auth-in-docusign) but the github link has been moved

I've searched on the docusign website how to implement the JWT flow (here : https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-get-token/) but we still need a user action to authenticate

Would someone have a solution ?

PS : if possible, a Java link would be more appreciated

Comment: Were you able to get a solution where there was never ever a need for consent through a browser, even once. I see the answers below and it still requires the first and only time consent, but when it is a stand along server with no UI or user interaction there is no one there to even do the first time consent.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Using JWT the user does not need to know anything, not IK, not key, you need nothing. The user doesn't need to log in, use email or password. There's nothing about auth needed. You can just build the app you want to do what you want for your user.

If you have one user in one account than you only have to consent once ever. You do it now and you'll never have to do it again.
That means you can then use JWT without any login UI or consent etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don't see how to do it. I need technical code too

Comment: you don't know how to do what? consent?

Comment: Edit this URL with your information and paste it into your browser. Then log in with your account and proceed. That's it.
https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id=7c2b8d7e-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-cda8a50dd73f&redirect_uri=http://example.com/callback/

Comment: Well you might have not well understood my question. Or I haven't understood your answer. I never want the user to access this URL in his browser. I want this to be done fluently. I'm going to edit my question

Comment: you can do it one time can you? after that it will not have to be done ever, by any user

Comment: I've edited my question. This might be easier to understand. I would prefer the user never sees what happens "behind the scene". And easier to deal with for me

Comment: yes, the answer is that with JWT the user doesn't see or do anything with authentication at all.

Comment: OK, so if understand, I just have to copy your previous URL, translate it with Java and get the result back ?
If that is so easy I will try tomorrow. It's a bit late for me :)

Comment: not sure what you mean by "translate it with Java". Java does not have to be involved in this part. You need to update it with the values, that may be also in your Java code, but you don't need Java to actually use this URL.

Comment: I've tried what you did. I think you did not understand what I really want. By calling this url I arrive on a login page. What I exactly want is to bypass this step for the user, so he doesnt need to enter his credentials. The credentials are known by the webapp

Comment: I did understand, and if you did this, then that's done and won't have to be done again.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the following:

A signer uses your web app to sign something by pushing a button in your web app. You do not want the signer to need to sign in/consent with DocuSign.

Solution:

1. Create a DocuSign user account "hr@example.com" This will be the "system" account that will send the envelope.
2. After creating the client id (integration key) for your application, the hr@example.com user must grant your application consent. This is done via an individual consent url. [More information](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/oauth-jwt-granting-consent). This is a one time operation.
3. When the signer pushes the "sign" button, your web app does the following:
4. Either use a current access token or create a new one via the JWT grant process.
5. Create and send the envelope with the access token
6. Obtain a Recipient View URL for the envelope. This is the URL for the signing ceremony.
7. Redirect the web app user (the signer) to the signing ceremony URL.
8. The signer signs. Their browser is then redirected back to your web app
9. Done.

### Added

As discussed in this answer and in Inbar's answer, your app can use the JWT grant on the app's server to obtain an access token and send out the envelope for signing.

The user being impersonated by the JWT grant can be a "system user" such as "eSignature@app.com"

Yes, the user being impersonated by the JWT grant will need to consent to the app. That is a one time process that you, the app inventor, can handle entirely by yourself if you control the DocuSign account.

Note that your application will need to have an ISV or ISV-L contract with DocuSign (no charge).

Comment: Hi Larry, thanks for your answer. I've understood I had not explained my problem clearly, so I've edited my question. Could you read it and tell me if you have a solution for it ?

Comment: Thanks. I try this and I answer you back

Comment: Larry, I still have a problem. I tried to follow the instructions on the blog and on the docusign page. But there must be some missing information. I can't process from my localhost server. I've added the redirection URI in the app account. It works when I ask for consent from my browser (I'm well redirected), but the same request for consent from my localhost server fails and seems to display the login confirmation.

Comment: Following my last post. The one time consent is not explained on the blog, especially for the ISV which seems to be the one I need. Do you have a clear information ? At this time I cannot implement the solution

Comment: I'm sorry that you're still having a problem. please contact our developer support team to ask these types of questions:
Open a case at the [support portal](https://support.docusign.com/en/contactSupport) (use the `DocuSign API’s Integration Support` option)